# how to update data in a database as much as data contained in arrays in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach, eloquent

I want to update the data in the database with the data in my array, I use Foreach to update my data, but I get an error like this

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object", exception: "ErrorException
```

there is my array

```
array:35 [
  0 => array:5 [
    "id" => 1
    "post_categori" => "internet"
    "status" => "active"
  ]
  1 => array:5 [
    "id" => 2
    "post_categori" => "banking"
    "status" => "active"
  ]
```

this is code in my controller

```
foreach($data as $data)
        {
            $results = Post::where('user_id','=', $data->id)
                        ->first();
            $results->status = $data->status;
            $results->save();
        }
```

so here I want to change all the status in the database to the status in my array, according to the same user_id (in my database) same with $array-> id

Comment: ```foreach($data as $data)
        {
            $results = Post::where('user_id','=', $data->id)
                        ->first();
if(!empty($results){
            $results->status = $data->status;
            $results->save();
}
        }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using **array** data so use like below.

```
foreach($data as $da)
{
      $results = Post::where('user_id','=', $da['id'])->first();
      $results->status = $data['status'];
      $results->save();
}
```

Comment: i get some error Creating default object from empty value"

Answer (score 0):

you are looping through an array not an object , change $data->id to $data['id']